# Flowable.compose() with org.reactivestreams.Processor<T, R>

Tags: rx-java2

Is there a way to `.compose()` a `Flowable` with an `org.reactivestreams.Processor<T, R>` to convert a `Flowable<T>` to a `Flowable<R>`?

Right now I'm `.subscribe()`'ing and then `Flowable.fromPublisher()`'ing the processor, but I'd like to be able to do something like

```java
Flowable.just(t)
  .compose(getProcessor())
  .subscribe(r -> {});
```

instead of what I'm doing now:

```java
Processor<T, R> processor = getProcessor();
Flowable.just(t).subscribe(processor);
Flowable.fromPublisher(processor).subscribe(r -> {});
```

Comment: No. Composing over an arbitrary processor is risky because it could leave the processor hanging in the middle. That's why we have `publish(Function)` and `replay(Function)` which use a kind of PublishProcessor and ReplayProcessor internally, but with the right lifecycle managements for them and the upstream.

Comment: Hmm, okay. Do you know of an idiomatic way to do something like that? Specifically, the processor in the middle can start to emit content even without it being `onNext`'d, so the standard operators don't seem to fit here.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. The `BehaviorProcessor` can start with an item like that.

Comment: But I guess I can't compose over that?